# Enable copy-paste in jquery-terminal?

Tags: jquery-terminal

I'm using jquery-terminal to provide an interactive prompt in javascript.  Unfortunately, I cannot paste things into this prompt.

How do I paste text into jquery-terminal?

Comment: Pasting don't work in Safari on Mac OSX

Comment: I'm on Firefox on Linux.  I opened https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/issues/223

Comment: Pasting works now on Safari in Mac OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasting may be done with Ctrl-V on non-Mac machines.  The paste options do not appear in the right-click context menu, which was misleading me.